# Can you help me to explain the second sentence in this paragraph

Tags: grammar

The eighteenth century was not one in which powered sculptural conceptions were developed. **Add to this the timidity with which unschooled artisans - originally trained as stonemasons, carpenters, or cabinetmakers - attacked the medium from which they sculpture made in the United States in the late eighteenth century.**

Comment: Where is this from? It doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: Please provide attribution for the quotation, as well as a link to the source (if possible).

Comment: “Add to this the timidity with which unschooled artisans — originally trained as stonemasons, carpenters, or cabinetmakers — attacked the medium from which they were to make their images, and one understands more fully the development of sculpture made in the United States in the late eighteenth century.“ From something on langlib

Comment: https://www.langlib.com/Reading/SentenceAnalysis/ReadingSentence/NDE5LTMtMg==

Comment: Thank you Xanne. It is from a TOEFL test. Many sources on the Internet gave the garbled quote as I posted. I read the sentence in the link you gave and it is much clearer. Thank you.